# Get year of end date within date between

Tags: powerbi, dax

I use as a filter date between.

I would like to get the year of the end date. I try as measure yearmax=year(max(date)) but it returns wrong values. I need to extract only the year of the end date. For example, when the user select as date range 01/03/2020 till 04/04/2027, I need to get only the year of the end date and have 2027.
I put the pbix file here, any help would be appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AqrdiHBQdYjrQImP9AGO_sC7Duh9Yeb5/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Power BI slicer visual bug.
You set filter into the slicer to restrict the selection over the last 90 days including TODAY. When selecting any day up to yesterday, your YEAR(MAX('Date'[Date])) measure works fine. But when you push the slicer up to today, then even if the slicer shows the correct date of today in the upper bound, the measure returns the last year in the date table, like when no filter exists. To fix that you might add a filter to your measure to limit the upper bound to TODAY() like follows

```
Year end date = 
VAR MaxDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ), KEEPFILTERS ( 'Date'[Date] <= TODAY () ) )
RETURN
    YEAR ( MaxDate )
```

Of course, maybe that the problem was just the existence of the filter in the slicer, and by removing it the original measure works ad desired